# LaTeX - Define a list of words to use a certain font

Tags: latex

#### Problem

I'm writing an essay/documentation about an application. Within this doc there are a lot of `code`-words which I want to be highlighted using a different font. Currently I work with:

```
{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont SOME-KEY-WORD}
```

Which is a bit of work to use every time.

#### Question

I'm looking for a way to declare a list of words to use a specific font within the text.
I know that I can use the *listings* package and define `morekeywords` which will be highlighted within the listings-environment but I need it in the text.

I thought of something like this:

```
\defineList{\fontfamily{cmtt}}{
    SOME-KEY-WORD-1,
    SOME-Key-word-2,
    ...
}
```

#### EDIT

I forgot to mention that I already tried something like:

```
\def\somekeyword{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont some\_key\_word\normalfont}
```

which is a little bit better then the first attempt but I still need to use `\somekeyword` in the text.

#### EDIT 2

I came upon a workaround:

```
\newcommand{\cmtt}[1]{{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont #1\normalfont}}
```

It's a little better then EDIT but still not the perfect solution.

Comment: have a look at the `chickenize` package if you want to highlight "normal" words, or listings if the words might contain special symbols

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I will take a look. Thank you.

Comment: So it seems like the `chickenize` package only works for lunaTex.

Comment: Why do you need a custom `\cmtt` macro? Why not use `\texttt{foo}` instead? Or `\verb|foo|` if the content is fragile?

Comment: The idea was to create a list of words/phrases which would be automatically styled in another font.

Comment: As I said, if you want an automatic solution, the magic of lualatex can help (or maybe wrapping the whole content into `lstlistings` environments....)

Answer (score -1):

Substitution every time a word occurs, without providing any clues to TeX, might be difficult and is beyond my skills (though I'd be interested to see someone come up with a solution).

But why not simply create a macro for each of those words?

```
\newcommand\somekeyword{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont SOME-KEY-WORD}
```

Use like this:

```
Hello, \somekeyword{} is the magic word!
```

The trailing `{}` are unfortunately necessary to prevent eating the subsequent whitespace; even the built-in `\LaTeX` command requires them.

If you have very many of these words and are worried about maintainability, you can even create a macro to create the macros:

```
\newcommand\declareword[2][]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand%
    \csname\if\relax#1\relax#2\else#1\fi\endcsname%
    {{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont #2}}%
}
\declareword{oneword}          % defines \oneword
\declareword{otherword}        % defines \otherword
\declareword[urlspy]{urls.py}  % defines \urlspy
...
```

The optional argument indicates the name of the command, in case the word itself contains characters like `.` which cannot be used in the name of a command.

Comment: The macros work the same way as `\def\someKeyWord` right? So I would still need to replace every occurrence of **someKeyWord** to `\someKeyWord` or did i get the function of macro wrong?

Comment: Yes, you would still need to change your text. Like I said, there is no way around that (that I know of).

Comment: I tried your solution. Ran into a problem if there is a '.' in the phrase: `urls.py` for example. The solution I showed in EDIT2 doesn't seem to have a problem with that.

Comment: Yes, it won't work if the "word" contains characters that are not valid in macro names. I'll edit to add a workaround.

Comment: I'll try it out asap